# is it ok for arguments and expects go out of scope

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++17, googletest, googlemock

I'm wondering is it ok if arguments and expects are going out of scope when they actually be matched later? like this:

```
struct Object
{
    // ...
};

struct TestFixture : public testing::Test
{
    MOCK_METHOD1(handle, void(Object obj));
};

TEST_F(TestFixture, Basic)
{
    {
        Object obj; // = get different obj
        EXPECT_CALL(*this, handle(obj));
    }

    {
        Object obj; // = get different obj
        EXPECT_CALL(*this, handle(obj));
    }

    {
        Object obj; // = get different obj
        EXPECT_CALL(*this, handle(obj));
    }

    // call handle 3 times
}
```

all the 3 `obj` variable will go out of scope, also will `EXPECT_CALL` create some kind of local variables there? Is this test ok in gtest? Thanks.

Comment: The way I see it, the handle function will make a copy of Object. However putting mock methods on the TestFixture seems strange to me, usually they should be on a MockObject that is derived from an abstract base class (interface). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Mock is on another type, I tried to simplify the code, my question is the same.

Comment: What prevents you from running it and watch the behavior?

Comment: this is C++, a program doesn't crash doesn't mean it is behaving good, think about UB.

Comment: There is no problem with EXPECT_CALL going out of scope. Here is one example from Google Test documents, where `EXPECT_CALL` is in the scope of a for loop: http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_for_dummies.html#StickyExpectations

Also you can use [address sanitizer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhpzDFvXopk) or UB sanitizer to check your code against UB.

Comment: This is not Groovy! Why was it tagged [tag:gmock], Groovy mocking framework?

Comment: ah you are right, it should be [googlemock] instead, fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [reference/matchers.html](http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/matchers.html)

> Except `Ref()`, these matchers make a copy of value in case it’s modified or destructed later.

So you are fine.